# Windows Phone 8 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke not working async

Tags: wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, event-dispatching

I am new to async programming and to WP8 , this is my first app and I have some issues with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(..)

In my code behind the view class, i am trying to load data in a Pivot scree async for the second tab.

Here is what i have right now :

```
public partial class ReminderPivot : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        #region Reminder Members
        private ReminderViewModel _model;
        private IRepository _repository;
        #endregion Reminder Members

        #region Constructors
        public ReminderPivot()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _model = new ReminderViewModel();
            _repository = new LocalStorageRepository();

            LoadData();
            LoadAsyncData();

            this.DataContext = _model;

        }
        #endregion Constructors

        public void LoadData()
        {
            IEnumerable<Reminder> activeList = _repository.GetRemindersByStatusId(2);
            if (activeList != null)
            {
                foreach (var reminder in activeList)
                {
                    _model.ActiveReminders.Add(reminder);
                }
            }
        }
        public void LoadAsyncData()
        {            
            Action action = () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);

                IEnumerable<Reminder> inactiveList = _repository.GetRemindersByStatusId(3);
                if (inactiveList != null)
                {
                    _model.InctiveReminders = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Reminder>(inactiveList);
                }
            };

           Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
        }
```

The thing is that this STILL blocks my UI thread. What am i missing here?

EDIT :
The idea is to load data async into the ViewModel ObservableCollection wich is ModelBinded in the XAML.

If i try to make the call async on another thread with Task.Factory(...) etc lets say, this crashes as i am changing the binding from another thread not UI thread.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that suggests an asynchronous usage... `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` will execute your code on the UI thread, it's only getting dispatched to be executed later!

Comment: Hi @PedroLamas. then the question is, how can i load is async? If i try with Task.Factory(..) and create it on a separate thread, then it will crash because my list that i am updating is binded to the ListBox..

Comment: Seems to me that using `Task.Factory` is a definitely the best possibility here...

Comment: re-trying it now :-p finders crossed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the suggestion of @PedroLamas i made it work, not sure if this is the nicest way or the most elegant but it gets the job done.

Im making the call that takes time to complete on another thread with Task.Factory and making it awaitable, and at the end just update the UI with the Dispatcher.

```
public async void LoadAsyncDataWithTask()
        {
            IEnumerable<Reminder> inactiveList = null;
            Action action = () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                inactiveList = _repository.GetRemindersByStatusId(2);
            };

            await Task.Factory.StartNew(action);

            Action action2 = () =>
            {
                if (inactiveList != null)
                {
                    foreach(var item in inactiveList)
                    {
                        _model.InctiveReminders.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            };

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action2);

        }
```

Comment: That'll work (+1). You might do a bit better by making `GetRemindersByStatusId` async to keep things tidier at this level: it depends on the rest of your code.

Comment: With Windows Phone 8 I've been able to do things like this placing async in front of a lambda:

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(125);

        TClock.RestTimerCanvas.Children.Clear();
    });

Answer (score 1):

While what you've found works and using `Task` is very up-to-date, by using `Thread.Sleep` you're still blocking a thread in the ThreadPool for no good reason.

You can avoid this by using a one-off `System.Threading.Timer` ([see MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)) which will fire on one of the (background) ThreadPool threads. Then use a `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)` at the end of your timer callback to update the UI.

For example:

```
        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
            state =>
                {
                    // ... your code to run in background

                    // ... call BeginInvoke() when done
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("done"));
                },
            null,
            5000,
            System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for the info,didn't know that +1. Thread.Sleep was just to test that the method is working (to simulate a bigger load time, much data processing , hard work etc). In the production code this kind of thing doesnt exist :-p.